# Endless loading when nginx in docker service (swarm mode)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have simple example in local machine:

```
docker service create --name nginx --publish 8080:80 --replicas 2 nginx:stable-alpine
```

And if i do

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

I get standart nginx page and it is ok

But when in chrome i type http://localhsot:8080
I take endless loading without answer. Can somebody explain why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker service create --name nginx --publish 8080:80 --replicas 2 nginx:stable-alpine

It Is Working Fine for me with curl as well as browser make sure you join as a swarm manager node

Comment: Is it required join another manager node? I thought when i do 'docker swarm init' I already have manager in local machine.

Comment: this command "docker service create --name nginx --publish 8080:80 --replicas 2 nginx:stable-alpine" works for  me , i am using docker-machine on mac , provide me your system info and error log if your are facing some ?

Comment: I notice, if I type http://127.0.0.1:8080 site is opened

Comment: @Billizzard your localhost is misconfigured. check etc/hosts file. it should be configure like this --> 127.0.0.1 localhost